# JPA - Persisting Entity causes other Entity's Collection to be Deleted

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem where, when persisting an entity, a collection in another entity is being deleted.

I have one Entity ("Container") (id 1), persisted with a single "Inner" in it's Collection of Inners.

When I come to persist another Container (id 3), again with another single Inner in it's Collection of Inners, the Inner from the first Entity is deleted.

I cannot think of a reason for this. Is there something wrong with my class annotations or any other explanation?

"Container" Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "container")
public class Container
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_seq")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    @JoinTable(name = "container_inner", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "container_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "inner_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    private Set<Inner> inners = new HashSet<>();
}
```

"Inner" Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INNER")
public class Inner
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Integer id = HelperUtils.defaultId;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, mappedBy = "inners")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Set<Container> containers = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Persist Code:

```
em.persist(container);
em.flush();
```

JPA Output:

```
Hibernate: insert into container [...]
Hibernate: delete from container_inner where container_id=?
```

H2 Output:

```
/*SQL #:1*/call next value for id_seq;
/*SQL l:539 #:1*/insert into container (ID) values {1: 3};
/*SQL */SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() WHERE SCOPE_IDENTITY() IS NOT NULL;
/*SQL l:84 #:1*/delete from container_inner where container_id=? {1: 1};
/*SQL */SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() WHERE SCOPE_IDENTITY() IS NOT NULL;
```